# Excel Stuck in Developer 'Design Mode'

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

We have a set of spreadsheets that contain scrollbars added in developer mode. Clicking these scrollbars changes a value and a diagram in the spreadsheet.

Suddenly these do not work. The mouse cursor changes to a multiple arrow symbol when hovering over the scrollbars- as if Excel is in design mode. Toggling design mode does nothing, and I have tried enabling lax security settings.

The documents in question work fine on other machines.

I have tried repairing the Office 2010 installation.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an update distributed through Microsoft Update. I removed all updates relating directly to Excel and Office Service Pack 2, and functionality was then restored.